# Particle in a infinite square potential; length of square instantaneously halved

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have the homework question:

"A particle is in the ground state of an infinite square potential well of length L.
What would be the result of an attempt to decrease the box's diameter to 1/2 L?"

The problem of instantaneously increasing the length of the box is fine for me.

When L is *increased* by a factor of k: $L \rightarrow kL$, the new state is a superposition of eigenstates of the new box: $|\psi\rangle\rightarrow|\phi\rangle=\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n |\phi_n\rangle$

and the probability of finding the particle in the $n^{th}$ excited state is $|c_n|^2$, with the coefficients given by $ |\langle\psi|\phi_n\rangle|^2=\int_0^{2L}\psi(x)^*\phi_n(x)dx=\int_0^L\psi(x)^*\phi_n(x)dx$

The important part about this is that the integral is only nonzero for 0 to L, since $\psi(x>L)=0$.

Now considering $k<1$, now $\phi_n(x)=0$ $\forall x>kL$, therefore the coefficients are given by $c(k)_n=\int_0^{kL}\psi(x)^*\phi_n(x)dx$. For $k=\frac{1}{2}: c_n(k)=4\sqrt{2}(-1)^n\frac{n}{\pi(1-4n^2)}$ (or so I have calculated), and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|c_n(k)|^2=\frac{1}{2}$, and when k=/=1/2 the sum follows an increasing function of kbetween 0 and 1.

This tracks for me mathematically, since as the box is instantaneously decreased in size, there is a probability of the particle being found outside the new box. If $k=\frac{1}{2}$ then there is a probability of a half that it's found outside, therefore the sum of the probabilities of it being found in any of the eigenstates of the new half box must be half.

My confusion comes from the physical interpretation of this observation: The total probability being a half must imply that there is a half probability that it is found outside the box, however this is impossible since it cannot exist in an infinite potential. Is this a paradox? Or is there a simpler solution? (assuming my maths is correct)

Comment: The problem when the well is suddenly shrunk is that the new eigenstates cannot be used to construct the old eigenstate, since the former vanish outside the well but the latter do not. To study the problem you could instead: 1. abandon the sudden approximation and look at the problem with a moving wall- in the case of constant there is an exact solution, or 2. replace the infinite well by a deep finite well and use the sudden approximation